# crypto/ssh ParsePublicKey "short read" error

Tags: go, ssh, key-pair

In a program I am developing I need a way to add public keys into the authorized_keys file during development, so I am using command line arguments to do so.

I have omitted most of the code, but if you would like to view all of the code, [here is the repository](https://github.com/george-e-shaw-iv/interactive-shell), with the problem line being located in main.go on line 20.

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Fatal error trying to read new public key file: %s", err)
}

newAuthorizedKey, err := ssh.ParsePublicKey(b)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Fatal error trying to parse new public key: %s", err)
}
```

The "short read" error comes from the `ssh.ParsePublicKey` function. The command line argument that I am passing in is the location of a public key to add to the authorized_keys file of this program (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`). I have ensured that the file is correctly being passed into the program.

I have looked at the source code in hopes of debugging this "short read" error, but I can't figure out what is going on. The location for source code of the `ParsePublicKey` function in `crypto/ssh` is located [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/keys.go#L246), and the location of source code of the `parseString` function, which is what the `ParsePublicKey` function is using to generate the "short read" error, is located [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/messages.go#L519), also in `crypto/ssh`.

Comment: The documentation for [`ParsePublicKey`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParsePublicKey) says it parses public keys in wire format, not the on disk format used by openssh.

Comment: Wasn't aware that there were multiple formats, is there a way to convert to wire format? @JimB

Comment: You don’t need to parse anything, id_rsa.pub _is_ the authorized_keys format. Most people add them on the cli just by appending them directly to the authorized_keys file.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to convert it into a `ssh.PublicKey` interface is because [`MarshalAuthorizedKey`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#MarshalAuthorizedKey) takes in a `ssh.PublicKey` interface and returns an authorized key ready to be appended to the authorized_keys file. Do they only have this function to get the key back into the format that it was on the disk? @JimB

Comment: No, they have that function for when you don’t already have a .pub file.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your help @JimB

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think some of the comments to the question lead at this, but the function `ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey([]byte)` is able to read interpret the file at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseAuthorizedKey

Your example should work like this:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Fatal error trying to read new public key file: %s", err)
}

newAuthorizedKey, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(b)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Fatal error trying to parse new public key: %s", err)
}
```