# Getting ssh: short read error when trying to parse a public key in golang

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to parse a public key using `go`'s `ssh` lib as follows:

```
var testPublicKey = `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...DEdfU= pkaramol@MacBookPro`


pubKey, err := ssh.ParsePublicKey(([]byte(testPublicKey)))
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ssh: short read
```

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016118/crypto-ssh-parsepublickey-short-read-error) question but it addresses a different issue (reading a public key from a file and loading to authorized keys list)

My goal is to end up with an `*rsa.PublicKey` [type](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#PublicKey) to be used in [this](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/blob/master/pkg/crypto/crypto.go#L35) function.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a different issue. It sounds like this function isn't decided to read the format as it is stored on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between the wire and disk format for the key. From the doc:

> ParsePublicKey parses an SSH public key formatted for use in the SSH wire protocol according to RFC 4253

So you need to marshal it to the wire format.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func parse(in []byte) error {
    // ParseAuthorizedKeys parses a public key from an authorized_keys file used in OpenSSH
    pk, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(in)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // pk.Marshal() Marshal returns the serialized key data in SSH wire format, with the name prefix
    // ssh.ParsePublicKey is used to unmarshal the returned data
    res, err := ssh.ParsePublicKey(pk.Marshal())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println(res)
    return nil

}

func main() {
    key := "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...DEdfU= pkaramol@MacBookPro"
    if err := parse([]byte(key)); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```